# Explain the usage of Client and Server components in Local Database Cache template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-sync-framework

Can someone please explain the *intended* purpose of the client and server components under the advanced "arrow" option in the Local Database Cache > Configure Data Synchronization dialog please?

I just want to call `SyncAgent.Synchronize()`. Why do I need the components, and how to use them? Why put them in a single project location or 2 different locations?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

some people prefer using an n-tier setup and the multi-project, separate client/server component setup allows them to keep the actual connection and synchronization tasks at the back end database on the server side wrapped in a WCF service.

Likewise, in the older Window Mobile based sync is also on a multi-project, n-tier setup.

Comment: I understand the n-tier set up. but I don't understand what it has to do with the synchronization. The wizard only walkthrough and create one set of Entities (EF), which I am not sure is for the server or the client or shared.

Comment: you mentioned EF, are you referring to Entity Framework? the Local Database Cache wizard never uses EF nor does it generated entities at all. are we referring to the same Local Database Cache wizard?

Comment: After working with it for a long time, I realised that if the wizard creates a new .sdf as opposed to using an existing sdf, it will immediately start up the Data Source Configuration wizard which allows me to choose DataSets or the EF stuff. I now realised that this is not required at all for the Sync. I was confused by exactly this step of the wizard.